# how to use sum function in sql joins

Tags: sql-server

How to use sum function in joins  in  sql server 2008?

```
SELECT SUM(d.TranTypeAmt),
       h.LnNo,
       h.LoanRcptAmt,
       d.Trantype,
       d.TranTypeAmt
FROM   LGen_LnInstClln_h h
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN LGen_LnInstClln_d d
         ON h.PK_Id = d.InstCllnHdr_FK
WHERE  h.LnNo = '40009'
```

Comment: What's the problem with the above SQL?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause turns the right outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a group by clause when using aggregate function, with other columns in the select list.

so here you should add

```
group by 
h.LnNo,
       h.LoanRcptAmt,
       d.Trantype,
       d.TranTypeAmt
```

at the end of the query

Answer (score 2):

When using an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx), such as [`SUM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) you need to either use aggregate functions on the rest of the data items, or group by them.

```
select  SUM(d.TranTypeAmt), h.LnNo,h.LoanRcptAmt,d.Trantype,d.TranTypeAmt
from LGen_LnInstClln_h h 
right outer join LGen_LnInstClln_d d on h.PK_Id=d.InstCllnHdr_FK  
where h.LnNo='40009'
GROUP BY h.LnNo,h.LoanRcptAmt,d.Trantype,d.TranTypeAmt
```

Comment: The question says nothing about the cardinality of the relation between the tables. If one PK_Id matches multiple d.InstCllnHdr_FK, then the SUM function will sum up those multiple matches. Is this what kalaivanan wants?

Comment: by using the above query following error is displaying olumn 'LGen_LnInstClln_h.LnRcptNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @kalaivanan: h.LnRcptNo is not part of the SELECT list in this query. I think you accidentally changed it. What happens when you execute the query as it is, without changing anything?